# arbitrary $n$-dimensional matrix algebras in II$_1$ factor

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm struggling to show that in a type II$_1$ and any $n$ $\exists$ a  subfactor $M$ such that $M \cong M_n$ .

I suppose it should follow from the isomorphism between the equivalence classes of projections and the interval $[0,\operatorname{tr}(1)]$ but i can not figure out the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your II$_1$-factor is $N$. You can always find projections $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ with $\sum_jp_j=I $ and $\tau(p_j)=1/n$. Because you are in a factor and they have equal trace, these projections are pairwise equivalent. In particular there exist partial isometries $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ such that $v_j^*v_j=p_j$, $v_jv_j^*=p_1$.

Next you define 
$$
e_{kj}=v_k^*v_j,\ \ \ k,j=1,\ldots,n.
$$
You have 
$$\tag1
e_{kj}e_{st}=v_k^*v_jv_s^*v_t=v_k^*v_jp_jp_sv_s^*v_t=\delta_{j,s}\,v_k^*v_jv_j^*v_t^*
=\delta_{j,s}\,v_k^*p_1v_t=\delta_{j,s}\,v_k^*v_t=\delta_{j,s}\,e_{kt}.
$$
Now let $M=\operatorname{span}\{e_{kj},\ k,j=1,\ldots,n\}\subset N$. Then the map $\pi:M\to M_n(\mathbb C)$ given by $\pi(e_{kj})=E_{kj}$ is a $*$-isomorphism. This is easily checked using $(1)$.

Comment: The $p_i$ must be pairwise orthogonal, right ?

Comment: Yes, they have to add to the identity if we want the subfactor to have the same identity (and this guarantees pairwise orthogonal). If we don't mind the identity, they just need to be pairwise orthogonal with equal trace.

Comment: How can you always find such a sum of projections? It is obvious you can find any projection of size 1/n but im not sure how you could find a sum of such projections equal to the identity

Comment: Because if $\tau(p_1)=1/n$, then $\tau(1-p)=1-1/n$ and you can find a $p_2\leq 1-p_1$ with $\tau(p_2)=1/n$. After $n$ steps you have $p_1,\ldots,p_n$, pairwise orthogonal, and the sum has trace 1.

Comment: Oh okay! I was struggling to see why under any projection you can choose a projection of any given trace and i suppose this is because in your proof above $(1-p_1)N(1-p_1)$ is a $\Pi_1$ factor itself so there exists $p_2$ inside it of trace $1/n$. Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, that's one way to see it. Glad I could help.